# jQuery ajax requests locking IE8. Cannot click to another page until request completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, navigation, locking, internet-explorer-8

I cannot seem to find anything about an async request locking up IE8 but it is happening to me.

The browser will not allow navigation away from the current page until the request completes.

Example: if I open page the script below does a request to place icons on a page based on additional data not available while building the page. While this request is made, navigation is locked.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You!

[Script pasted here!](http://pastebin.com/rMTa7hzs)

Answer (score 0):

try calling your script from setTimeout. This can solve a range of locking issues by moving execution to a 'pseudo' thread instead of holding the global loop.